# Mongoose sum operation in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection named `votes`:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a3cb59b2b8ded51693074d"),
        "Pseudo" : "Cacaboy",
        "Type" : "down",
        "postvote" : ObjectId("54a2f05bedbe1109145b06b6"),
        "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-12-31T10:02:34.209Z"),
        "__v" : 0
    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a3d776ecbf63c61a91d396"),
        "Pseudo" : "CosmicJB",
        "Type" : "up",
        "postvote" : ObjectId("54a2f05bedbe1109145b06b6"),
        "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-12-31T11:01:10.715Z"),
        "__v" : 0
    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a3dca5b2b8ded51693074e"),
        "Pseudo" : "hateman",
        "Type" : "down",
        "postvote" : ObjectId("54a2f05bedbe1109145b06b6"),
        "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-12-31T10:02:34.209Z"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

Implemented Aggregation pipeline:

```
Vote.aggregate({$match: {postvote: pvote}}, 
               {$group: {_id: '$Type', 
                         n: { $sum: 1 }
                        }},
               function(err, cb){
                  console.log(cb);
             });
```

Obtained o/p:

```
[ { _id: 'up', n: 1 }, { _id: 'down', n: 2 } ]
```

Desired Result, for a `postvote`:

- If `up` and `down` votes, both are present then `result:up-down`.
- If just `down` votes are present then, `result: -down`.
- If just `up` votes are present then `result:up`.

Is it possible using aggregation?

Comment: What does mean if up - down = result?

Comment: So you want to calculate the net votes?

Comment: @Barno a aggregate function to return voteUP subtract voteDOWN

Comment: yes @BatScream, i want calculate a vote according if voteup and votedown exist by postvote

Comment: @PixelPixel, Please do take care to format the question properly and to be precise in what you ask for. That would help your question get more attention. Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your aggregation pipeline to perform the below operations:

- `Match` the records with the desired `postvote` id(s).
- For each record, project an extra field named `weight`, for the records of `Type` - `up`, the 
  weight would be `1`, for the other `-1`.
- `Group` based on the `postvote` field, to `project` the sum of the `weight` field for the
  `postvote` as `result`.

Code:

```
Vote.aggregate(
{$match:{"postvote":pvote}},
{$project:{"postvote":1,"weight":{$cond:[{$eq:["$Type","up"]},1,-1]}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$postvote","result":{$sum:"$weight"}}},
function(err,data){
 // handle response.
}
)
```

Sample o/p:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54a2f05bedbe1109145b06b6"), "result" : -1 }
```

Comment: agree, I understand how to proceed now, thanx.